# Proving $A^n$ corresponds to a rotation of $n \theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

One of the properties of the rotation matrix in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ is the following:

$A^n$ corresponds to a rotation of $n \theta$

I am asked to prove this property. Is the standard induction proof below sufficient?

I ask because $n \in \mathbb{C}$ gives rotation matrices in MATLAB. Inputs such as $n=\frac{3}{4}, 3i$ seem to return rotation matrices.

Induction proof for if $A=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ then $A^n=\begin{bmatrix}cos(n\theta) & -sin(n\theta)\\sin(n\theta) & cos(n\theta)\end{bmatrix}$:

Let $n=1$ then $A^1=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}^1=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}$ which agrees.

Assume $n=k$ holds, $A^k=\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}^k=\begin{bmatrix}cos(k\theta) & -sin(k\theta)\\sin(k\theta) & cos(k\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

For $n=k+1$, $A^{k+1}=A^kA=\begin{bmatrix}cos(k\theta) & -sin(k\theta)\\sin(k\theta) & cos(k\theta)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\\sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}cos(k\theta)cos(\theta)-sin(k\theta)sin(\theta) & -cos(k\theta)sin(\theta)-sin(k\theta)cos(\theta)\\sin(k\theta)cos(\theta)+cos(k\theta)sin(\theta) & cos(k\theta)cos(\theta)-sin(k\theta)sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}cos(k\theta+\theta) & -sin(k\theta+\theta)\\sin(k\theta+\theta) & cos(k\theta+\theta)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}cos((k+1)\theta) & -sin((k+1)\theta)\\sin((k+1)\theta) & cos((k+1)\theta)\end{bmatrix}$

which agrees.

If $n=k$ is true then $n=k+1$ is true. Since $n=1$ is true then the initial statement is true for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

If the proof above is not sufficient, how would I go about proving this property (presumably for $n \in \mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: Yeah, this is fine. It might be better to start with the $n=2$ case but this is fine.

Comment: This proof is fine for the positive integers.

If you want to go just a bit further, you can prove that $A^{-1}$ is a rotation by $-\theta$ by doing the multiplication of your matrix with the same matrix but with a negative sign in front of each $\theta$ and showing that this gives the identity. Then you do induction backwards (i.e., assume for $n=-k$, show that this implies the result for $n=-k-1$). This gives the result for negative integers.

Finally, noting that $A^{0}$ is the identity matrix, which is indeed the matrix which rotates by $0\theta$, the result is proven for all integers.

Comment: A more efficient way to do would be to show that the angle addition laws work, i.e. if $A(\theta)$ and $A(\alpha)$ are the rotation matrices for angles $\theta$ and $\alpha$, that $A(\theta) A(\alpha) = A(\theta + \alpha)$. You could then iterate this addition law to get $A(\theta)^n = A(n \theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix $$M(n,\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(n\theta) & -\sin(n\theta)\\
\sin(n\theta) & \cos(n\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix},
$$

for $n \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.
We want to prove that $A^n = M(n,\theta)$.

The first thing to know to proceed is that:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\\
\end{bmatrix} = e^{\theta Q}, \text{where}~ Q = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) for further details on matrix exponential.

Therefore:

$$A^n = e^{n\theta Q} = M(n,\theta).$$

As a final remark, IMHO I don't feel really comfortable to define $A^n$ as a rotation matrix for $n \in \mathbb{C}$... What is the meaning of the complex angle $n\theta$?

Comment: This is probably the simplest way of proving it.